# CI when inserting arabic character it convert to?

Tags: codeigniter, mysqli, arabic, non-ascii-characters

i am developing json web-service using Codeigniter, when user POST Arabic character using web-service, in database it store like ????, but when i insert Arabic character using phpMyAdmin it working fine and also display well in web-service result, only issue with insert data.

in application/config/database.php

i used 'char_set' => 'utf8' and 'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci'

but still issue is there.

Comment: use `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` in your service method

Comment: i tried but its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any one arrise issue in particular table field in PhpMyadmin, so can you please go to phpMyadmin than change Collation (table related accroding field) like
  
        My Table Name : User ,
        My field name : user_name

```
 change it Collation latin1_swedish_ci to utf8_general_ci
```